# CallMethodAction: How do I refer to instance of a view as being TargetObject

Tags: silverlight

I know you'll use this to invoke method on the ViewModel, but just out of curiosity, how would you use to wire an event handler on the instance of the view, equivalent to wiring it in code behind.

Comment: Are you asking how you would have the method invoked as a response to an event _or_ how you would invoke an event handler as a method?

Comment: @AnthonyWJones: There is a TargetObject property on the CallMethodAction. I need to refer to the instance of the view where this trigger is located. I was able to refer to it by the name of the user control, but it gives me null reference error.

Answer (score 3):

The TargetObject is the object which has the method to be invoked, if you have the method in your window code-behind then the object is the window itself. You can bind to it by its name:

```
<UserControl xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
             ...etcetera...
             x:Name="UserControl">
```

So your CallMethodAction would be:

```
<ei:CallMethodAction MethodName="MyMethod"
                     TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=UserControl, Mode=OneWay}"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are probably after something like this (ignore that this specific example is best done with a command).

```
<Button Content="Click this">
   <i:Interaction.Triggers>
      <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
        <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding}" MethodName="SomeMethod" />
      </i:EventTrigger>          
   </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>
```

Comment: That doesn't work: the empty binding syntax refers to the current data context of the view, not the view itself.  In an MVVM scenario this lands you in the VM.